# How to gather the logits according to a 2D index?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Assume the sequence `[[2, 1, 4], [3, 4, 2]]` is generated by a pre-trained LSTM. It's dimension is `(2*3)` meaning `batch-size = 2` and `3 time steps` in each sample.

Then for example, there are `5 features` in total so the logits may be:

```
[[[0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2], 
  [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
  [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]],
 [[0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2],
  [0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2],
  [0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]]]
```

I want to use the sequence as the index to get the corresponding probabilities from the logits for each sample and each time step. Regarding the example above, the final result I want to get is

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.1]]
```

I knew that I probably need tf.stack() but I'm confused about how to handle the dimension. Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way.

```
tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels = None, logits = None)
```

`labels` is the index and `logits` is the output of a model.